# How do I add a permission check for many methods in a controller? (Filter, Action)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, aop, dry

I have the following at the beginning of many methods.

```
    if ((user.privilege & User.Privilege.WRITE) == 0) {
        session.setAttribute("alert", "You do not have permission to save.");
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/admin/home");
    }
```

How can I extract this and put it into a separate method that is called before many other controller methods, similar to Ruby on Rails `before_action :validate_privilege, [:save, :weekly_report, ...]`?

I found this in the docs, but it doesn't give any examples.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.19.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-embedded-container-servlets-filters-listeners

---

I found a way to do it based on @Deadpool's answer. It seems like it is more complicated than a simple annotation would be.

```
@Bean
public GenericFilterBean beforeAction() {
    String[] actions = new String[]{"/admin/censor", "/admin/weekly-report", "/admin/email-blast-submit"};
    return new GenericFilterBean() {
        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
//              System.out.println("requestURI:"+req.getRequestURI());
            boolean found = Arrays.stream(actions).anyMatch(req.getRequestURI()::equals);
            if (found) {
                User user = (User) req.getSession().getAttribute("user");
                if (user != null && (user.privilege & User.Privilege.WRITE) == 0) {
                    req.getSession().setAttribute("alert", "You do not have permission to save.");
                    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
                    res.sendRedirect("/admin/home");
                    return;
                }
            }
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    };
}
```

---

For the API using OAuth2, I used

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<...> delete(Principal principal, @RequestBody ...) throws ApiException {
    isAuthorized(principal, "ROLE_USER");
    ...

/** If not authorized, throw ApiException. */
private void isAuthorized(Principal principal, String role) throws ApiException {
    OauthClientDetail cd = userMapper.getOauthClientDetails(principal.getName());
    if (cd == null || cd.authorities == null || !cd.authorities.equals(role)) {
        throw new ApiException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, ...);
    }
}
```

(ApiException, OauthClientDetail (POJO), and UserMapper (MyBatis) are custom classes.)

Comment: You should be looking at Spring Security. In most cases, this would be done by annotating your controller (or a service method called by the controller) with an instruction like `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('WRITE')")`. (The expressions can be arbitrarily complicated, but it looks like in this case that a simple role would be sufficient.) Note also that Spring Boot is now on version 2.2, and you should use the new version for new applications.

Comment: @chrylis I attempted to use your suggestion for the API, but it didn't work. I added `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")` after `@ApiOperation` and `@RequestMapping` for `/api/v2/delete` and I updated `oauth_client_details` table setting `authorities = 'ROLE_MERCHANDISING'`. When I tried to access `/api/v2/delete` using the `client_id` that did not have `ROLE_USER`, then it still executed the API function.

Comment: You need to make sure that you follow all of the instructions for enabling Spring Security; the default `spring-boot-starter-security` would have required secured access generally for all endpoints, and you need to use `@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` on your configuration (you most probably missed this one).

Comment: @chrylis OK I added `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` on `public class ... extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` and it worked giving 'Access is denied' to `/api/v2/delete`, but when I changed it back with `update oauth_client_details set authorities = 'ROLE_USER'` it still denied access, so it's not very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for `Filter` to check each request for authorization you can use [Filter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter)

```
@Component
public class AuthFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void doFilter
  ServletRequest request, 
  ServletResponse response, 
  FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    LOG.info(
      "Starting a transaction for req : {}", 
      req.getRequestURI());

    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    LOG.info(
      "Committing a transaction for req : {}", 
      req.getRequestURI());
    }

     // other methods 
  }
```

or [GenericFilterBean](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter)

```
public class CustomFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

@Override
public void doFilter(
  ServletRequest request, 
  ServletResponse response,
  FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
       }
   }
```

Comment: You're suggesting reinventing the wheel when a standardized, tested, and solid solution is available.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Spring Security

```
 http.regexMatcher("/*") --> your base path or sth.
            .exceptionHandling()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable();

       http.addFilterAfter(authenticationProcessingFilter(),BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

Comment: Won't the basic authentication filter only use HTTP Basic Authentication with a single username and password?

Comment: I have a custom login page, and a custom Oauth2 API, and a custom 'remember me' function to auto-login by cookie, so I don't want to mess with the sensitive `ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` which can break the web pages. I use `@SessionAttribute(name="user", required=true) User user, // required for security` as arguments for each controller method to restrict access and `@ExceptionHandler({ServletRequestBindingException.class})
 public String handleMissingSession()` to handle logins and auto-logins.

Comment: In that code, we have added a fiter after BasicAuthenticationFilter. BasicAuthentication checks Authorization part. This filter checks anything you write. Or, we can disable basicauthentication. We can write our custom authentication.  @Chloe